# Using css translate causes space between divs

Tags: css, parallax, translate, skrollr

I am developing a site with parallax effect. I am using the skrollr.js plugin to achieve the desired parallax effect. 
After using 'background-position' and finding the effect jittery, I shifted to using the CSS translate() property as was suggested in many answers. However although most of the jitter has not disappeared (some exists due to the large img size I guess), now what I get is some space between two slides as it is evident here. Need to get rid of this space

[Demo](http://enginiku.allalla.com/demo/)

Having a tough time to figure out why this happens. Any help will be appreciated

**PS: I am using Bootstrap 3**

The relevant code is as follows -

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mortgage">
    <div class="bgrnd-img" data-anchor-target="#mortgage">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-trans" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li data-slide="1"><a href="">Mortgage</a></li>
                        <li data-slide="2"><a href="">Lending</a></li>
                        <li data-slide="3"><a href="">Insurance</a></li>
                        <li data-slide="4"><a href="">Testimonials</a></li>
                        <li data-slide="5"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="lending">
    <div class="bgrnd-img" data-anchor-target="#lending" data-top="transform: translate(0px,0px)" data-bottom-top="transform: translate(0px,250px)" data-slide="2">
        <div class="container display-table">
            <div class="row vgutter">
                <section class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                    At our company we offer you the truest advise for all your loan needs. From education to car to rentals, our expertise in lending benefits customers in making easy choices. 
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="insurance">
        <div class="bgrnd-img" data-anchor-target="#insurance" data-top="transform: translate(0px,0px)" data-bottom-top="transform: translate(0px,250px)" data-slide="3">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="testimonials">
        <div class="bgrnd-img" data-anchor-target="#testimonials" data-top="transform: translate(0px,0px)" data-bottom-top="transform: translate(0px,250px)" data-slide="4">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
        <div class="bgrnd-img" data-anchor-target="#contact" data-top="transform: translate(0px,0px)" data-bottom-top="transform: translate(0px,250px)" data-slide="5">

        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{    
width:100%;     
height:100%;  
}

body > div{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#mortgage .bgrnd-img{
background: url('../img/contact1.jpg');
}

#insurance .bgrnd-img{
background: url('../img/insurance1.jpg');
}

#lending .bgrnd-img{
background: url('../img/lending1.jpg');
}

#contact .bgrnd-img{
background: url('../img/contact1.jpg');
}

#testimonials .bgrnd-img{
background: url('../img/testimonials1.jpg');
}

.bgrnd-img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover !important;
}

.navbar-default{
min-height: 80px;
transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{
line-height: 40px;
color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-trans{
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
}

.navbar-bgrnd{
background-color: #0cb4eb;
border: none;
}

.display-table{
display: table;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
}

.vgutter{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var s = skrollr.init({

    forceHeight: false,
    smoothScrolling: false
});

//Initialize variables
var links = $(".navbar-nav").find("li");
slide = $(".bgrnd-img");
mywindow = $(window);
htmlbody = $('html,body');

//Scroll to a particular section on click
function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
    htmlbody.animate({
        scrollTop: $('.bgrnd-img[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top
    }, 1000, 'easeInOutQuint');
}

links.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});

//Change header background on scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(scroll <= 0){

        $(".navbar-default").removeClass("navbar-bgrnd");
        $(".navbar-default").addClass("navbar-trans");
    }
    else{

        $(".navbar-default").addClass("navbar-bgrnd");
        $(".navbar-default").removeClass("navbar-trans");
    }
});

});
```

Comment: translate is basically moving your element.. if you want the images to be moving while still attached to each other, I think you DO need to use background-position unless you want to start layering the elements to go one on top of the other..

Comment: If you still want to use translate try setting 'data-bottom-top:translate(0px,0px);' and 'data-top:translate(0px,-250px)'.. something like that

Comment: No, the above suggestion did not solve the issue :(

Comment: Hey actually got rid of the space. Thanx for clearing the concept @webkit. I used this in the code -
 
data-top="transform: translate(0px,0px)" data--250-top="transform: translate(0px,250px)"

Comment: sounds good.. just make sure all the rest of the images don't 'loose touch' through out the page, do you have the demo updated?

Comment: Here is the updated demo - 

http://enginiku.allalla.com/demo/demo.html

Comment: nice. I would definitely reduce the size of the pictures to lighten the page up.. I still think the page would benefit from a parallax effect moving the backgrounds upwards slower then the scroll.. maybe even a fixed attachment on the first opening background.. that's just my opinion though.